# What are the medical care costs for visitors to New Zealand who contract COVID-19?

Tags: new-zealand, covid-19

COVID-19 is an illness rather than an accident, so it's [not covered by New Zealand's ACC scheme](https://www.acc.co.nz/im-injured/injuries-we-cover/what-we-dont-cover/).

What are the out of pocket costs for New Zealand visitors who suspect they might be infected, and those of obtaining treatment if necessary?

NZ visitors are [not eligible for publicly funded health services](https://www.health.govt.nz/new-zealand-health-system/eligibility-publicly-funded-health-services/guide-eligibility-publicly-funded-health-services), and aside from [Australia and the UK](https://www.health.govt.nz/new-zealand-health-system/eligibility-publicly-funded-health-services/reciprocal-health-agreements), no other countries have reciprocal healthcare agreements with the New Zealand.

Comment: There is an [eligibility exemption for infectious diseases](https://www.health.govt.nz/new-zealand-health-system/eligibility-publicly-funded-health-services/guide-eligibility-publicly-funded-health-services/eligibility-limited-range-publicly-funded-health-services-0/people-receiving-treatment-infectious-diseases). However, general practitioners may still charge a fee.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.